# How long would it take for down becoming the opposite on earth?

Tags: time, rotational-kinematics, earth

Sorry if the question is unclear, I will try to explain it better.
Let's say that I am standing still somewhere on the planet and I say while pointing at my feet :"Down is this way", how much would I have to wait for the earth to rotate me to a point where by saying down and pointing down I would be pointing the opposite way compared to the previous down.

For the location I believe that the equator would be the only possible solution and it would take approximately 12 hours.

Could you tell me if my answer is correct and if there is another solution then what is it? For the starting time and location use what you prefer.

[image: Earth rotation]

Comment: "Down" is always towards the centre of the earth so yes, the only place where it could become the opposite direction is on the equator, and the time is 12 hours.

Comment: Let’s not forget plate tectonics - you just might have to wait a _really_ long time…

Comment: Actually, for practical purposes, down is the direction indicated by a plumb bob.  In middle latitudes, that points a little south of the center of the earth due to the earth's rotation and equatorial bulge.